# How to (temporarily) avoid a digest cycle when editing a scope variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, scope, digest

I want to edit an array of objects, which are tied to the view by an `ng-repeat`.
How can I avoid updating the scope until the complete array has been modified?

Here is a simple example:

I would like to update every obj in array and ONLY then update the $scope. Since the array contains objects I cannot simply copy them over in another variable.

```
<div ng-click="updateAll()" ng-repeat="obj in array">obj.value</div>

angular.module("test", []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.array = [{val: 1}, {val: 2}, {val: 3});

    $scope.updateAll = function() {
        for (var i = $scope.array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            $scope.array[i].val2 = i;
        };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your only possibility is to edit another array and set it to your original array as soon as all updates are done.

Comment: My array contains objects. I would hate to deep clone it (might loose data, like getters...)

Comment: why do you want this behavior? Do you show a list of the items and provide a possibility to update them, one after another and don´t want to have the items saved before the user clicked save or something similiar?

Comment: It is simply a performance issue. I do not want to update the $scope 150 times for all my objects if one update would suffice...